# Find the closest manager with 2x salary using hierarchy - PostgresSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with employeeid,bossid,salary.
I have created a hierarchy of all the direct and indirect managers of every employee.

```
employeeid | bossid | salary | hierarchy
20          NULL     10000       0
10           20       4500       1
50           10       3000       2
70           10        1500      2
40           50        1500      3
60           70        2000      3
30           50        1501      3

Manager = boss
Indirect manager = direct boss OR Boss of Boss
So for employee 30, boss = 50 and indirect = 50, 10 , 20
```

I want for each employee to find that employee's lowest ranked indirect boss in the hierarchy who earns at least twice as much as the employee.

This is the query I have used to create the hierarchy. I do not know how to proceed

```
with recursive EmpMgrCTE
as
(SELECT id,name,boss_id,salary, 0 as EmployeeLevel
from employees a
where boss_id is null
union all
select emp.id,emp.name,emp.boss_id,emp.salary,mgr.EmployeeLevel + 1 as EmployeeLevel
from employees emp
inner join EmpMgrCTE mgr
on emp.boss_id = mgr.id
)
select * 
from EmpMgrCTE emp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting the recursion with the top (bossid is null),
it can start with all others.

In the recursion it's possible to put the starting id & salary in extra columns which won't change through the recursive loop.

In this example the loop stops as soon a much higher boss salary was found.

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE EmpCTE AS
> (
>     SELECT emp.employeeid, emp.salary, emp.bossid
>     , 0 as Level
>     , emp.employeeid AS BaseEmployeeId
>     , emp.salary AS BaseEmployeeSalary
>     FROM employees emp
>     WHERE bossid IS NOT NULL
>     
>     UNION ALL
>     
>     SELECT mgr.employeeid, mgr.salary, mgr.bossid
>     , cte.Level + 1
>     , cte.BaseEmployeeId
>     , cte.BaseEmployeeSalary
>     FROM EmpCTE cte
>     JOIN employees mgr
>       ON mgr.employeeid = cte.bossid
>     WHERE BaseEmployeeSalary*2 > cte.salary
> )
> SELECT 
>   BaseEmployeeId AS EmployeeId
> , BaseEmployeeSalary AS EmployeeSalary
> , Level
> , employeeid AS BossId
> , salary AS BossSalary
> FROM EmpCTE emp
> WHERE BaseEmployeeSalary*2 <= salary
> ORDER BY BaseEmployeeId
> ```
>
> ```
> employeeid | employeesalary | level | bossid | bosssalary
> ---------: | -------------: | ----: | -----: | ---------:
>         10 |           4500 |     1 |     20 |      10000
>         30 |           1501 |     2 |     10 |       4500
>         40 |           1500 |     1 |     50 |       3000
>         50 |           3000 |     2 |     20 |      10000
>         60 |           2000 |     2 |     10 |       4500
>         70 |           1500 |     1 |     10 |       4500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a65f1ffde1e38d2e9dc8115292b6a2ef)*